# Как изменить строковый элемент массива и запушить измененый вариант в изначальный массив?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть изначальный массив `gridTemplateAreasArray`, который состоит из одного элемента.
У элемента такое значение:

```js
'"sources auto" "clicks auto" "shows auto" "conversion-price auto" "price auto" "conversion auto" "sales auto"'
```

Мне нужно через JS перезаписать этот массив так, чтобы у него вид был:

```js
[
  '"sources auto" "clicks auto" "shows auto" "conversion-price auto" "price auto" "conversion auto" "sales auto"',
  '"sources_twin_1 auto" "clicks_twin_1 auto" "shows_twin_1 auto" "conversion-price_twin_1 auto" "price_twin_1 auto" "conversion_twin_1 auto" "sales_twin_1 auto"'
]
```

Имеющийся код

```js
const table = document.querySelector('.table'),
        tableArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.table__article');
  
const gridTemplateAreas = window.getComputedStyle(table).gridTemplateAreas;
const gridTemplateAreasArray = window.getComputedStyle(table).gridTemplateAreas.split();
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: разделите строку по `" "`; из элементов уберите `auto`; добавьте `_twin1`; верните `auto` и склейте обратно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [`"sources auto" "clicks auto" "shows auto" "conversion-price auto" "price auto" "conversion auto" "sales auto"`]
arr[1] = arr[0].split(/"\s+"/g).map((i) => i.replace(/\s+/, '_twin_1 ')).join('" "')
console.log(arr)
```

UPDATE: от @teran
!!! Но только при условии что в конце фразы всегда  `auto"`

```js
const arr = [`"sources auto" "clicks auto" "shows auto" "conversion-price auto" "price auto" "conversion auto" "sales auto"`]
arr[1] = arr[0].replace(/(\s+auto")/, "_twin_1$1")
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: можно просто `(\s+auto")` заменить на `_twin_1$1`

Comment: @teran ТОЧНО, там же везде "auto"